# Android Studio Implement Abstract Method Shortcut

Tags: android-studio, shortcut

How can implement in current class every abstracts methods quickly from her extended classes in Android Studio?

For example, in Eclipse, putting mouse over warning and pressing on implement abstract methods message do it automatically.

Answer (score 18):

`android studio` Right click than Select `Generate..` or  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and get list of methods you can add into your `Activity`

For more to Implementing Methods of an Interface  IntelliJ IDEA  check https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/implementing-methods-of-an-interface.html

Comment: For Mac, option + Enter

Comment: for me enter only add in 1 of the methods, I have to repeat this short cut for all methods, is there a way to add in ALL method?

Answer (score 11):

`(control + return) -> Implement methods` on Macs

Answer (score 8):

shortcut to add methods in android studio `( Alt+insert)`

Answer (score 6):

**Windows:**

`Alt + Insert`  => Shows a dialog that has options to implement various things like constructor, abstract methods, inherited methods...

`Ctrl + I`  => Directly shows the abstract methods to implement.

`Ctrl + O`  => Shows a list of inherited methods to implement.

**Mac:**

`control + return`  => Shows a dialog that has options to implement various things like constructor, abstract methods, inherited methods...

`control + I`  => Directly shows the abstract methods to implement.

`control + O`  => Shows a list of inherited methods to implement.

> Keep the mouse pointer inside the class when using these shortcuts.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>CtRl</kbd>+ <kbd>I</kbd>

will give a small pop up of relevant methods to implement.

If there is no ambiguity for what is needed, all items are selected by default and you can simply hit enter to add the methods in quickly. Otherwise, you can ctrl+click the methods in the pop up to select multiple specific methods.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press Alt+Insert inside your class
2. Type override to find Override Methods item
3. Select your favorite method and press enter

**Edit:**

Today I saw a Tip in Android Studio startup which says somthing like this:

> You can use `Ctrl + o` inside a class to override methods!

Answer (score 0):

Which Android-Studio version are you using? I'm using Android-Studio 0.3.6 and this is working pretty similar to eclipse just hover the error , click the red light and Android-Studio offers you to generate the missing methods.

Comment: Did you mean 0.3.6 really? 0.3.6 is my version too, but Android Studio not offer to me any solution clicking or moving over red light to generate missing abstract methods.

Comment: Yeah i mean version 0.3.6, it's working without problems for me, but you could try to press 'ALT+INSERT' that's the shortcut for generating code...

Answer (score 0):

if you are overriding methods press Alt+insert pop up will be appear select the override methods and go for desire methods

Answer (score 0):

You can either

- "Generate Code" (Command + N), then select **"Implement methods"**. For example, in Android Studio with this Flutter app:
- Or just **"Implement methods"** (Control + I), and select your method:

These methods need to be abstract methods (e.g. abstract method in abstract class or method in an interface), and not implemented elsewhere. To override those, use **"Override methods"** instead.

[image]